# Oracle; Create custom pivot from table

Tags: sql, oracle11g, group-by, pivot

Ich have this:

```
ZN  BTG     BST FS  IST         D
161 18262   BC  An  1577861387  1,8
161 18262   BC  Ab  1577861875  3,9
161 18262   FK  An  1577862769  3,8
161 18262   FK  Ab  1577863033  0,2
161 18262   B   An  1577863670  -0,2
161 18262   B   Ab  1577863866  1,1
```

But i want this:

```
ZN  BTG   BC An      BC An  BC Ab      BC Ab  Fk An      Fk An  FK Ab  FK Ab  B An  B An  B Ab  B Ab
161 18262 1577861387 1,8    1577861875 3,9    1577862769 3,8  ......
```

I don't know where to start.
Thanks.

Comment: Does 'custom' imply that you don't know the values you might have in BST/FS, or even how many values and combinations - so you don't know how many columns you want in the final result, and it will vary with the data? If so that's something a reporting layer should probably deal with, not SQL. You can use dynamic SQL or an XML pivot but not sure that's really what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a fixed set of values the you can use a `PIVOT` with multiple keys:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
PIVOT ( MAX(ist) AS ist, MAX(d) AS d FOR (bst, fs) IN (
  ('BC', 'An') AS bc_an,
  ('BC', 'Ab') AS bc_ab,
  ('FK', 'An') AS fk_an,
  ('FK', 'Ab') AS fk_ab,
  ('B',  'An') AS b_an,
  ('B',  'Ab') AS b_ab
) )
```

So for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ZN, BTG, BST, FS, IST, D ) AS
SELECT 161, 18262, 'BC', 'An', 1577861387, '1,8'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 161, 18262, 'BC', 'Ab', 1577861875, '3,9'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 161, 18262, 'FK', 'An', 1577862769, '3,8'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 161, 18262, 'FK', 'Ab', 1577863033, '0,2'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 161, 18262, 'B',  'An', 1577863670, '-0,2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 161, 18262, 'B',  'Ab', 1577863866, '1,1'  FROM DUAL
```

This outputs:

> ```
>  ZN |   BTG |  BC_AN_IST | BC_AN_D |  BC_AB_IST | BC_AB_D |  FK_AN_IST | FK_AN_D |  FK_AB_IST | FK_AB_D |   B_AN_IST | B_AN_D |   B_AB_IST | B_AB_D
> --: | ----: | ---------: | :------ | ---------: | :------ | ---------: | :------ | ---------: | :------ | ---------: | :----- | ---------: | :-----
> 161 | 18262 | 1577861387 | 1,8     | 1577861875 | 3,9     | 1577862769 | 3,8     | 1577863033 | 0,2     | 1577863670 | -0,2   | 1577863866 | 1,1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f28a2b1f959a363529e2e32dd7a96e0e)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select zn, btg,
       max(case when bst = 'BC' and fs = 'An' then ist end) as bc_an_ist
       max(case when bst = 'BC' and fs = 'An' then d end) as bc_an_d,
       max(case when bst = 'BC' and fs = 'Ab' then ist end) as bc_ab_ist
       max(case when bst = 'BC' and fs = 'Ab' then d end) as bc_ab_d,
       . . .
from t
group by zn, btg
```